# Why is my Java program stuck in a infinite while-loop for some values?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

I just started with java and while I was doing a exercise (about finding the next Friday 13th after a given date) when I got stuck with the following problem: When the input day (of the given date) is equal or bigger than 13, the program goes in a infinite loop. Any suggestions?

```
      public class NextFriday13 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int d = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int m = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        //aqui colocaremos o total de dias em cada mes
        int[] DAYS = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
        //fixaremos nosso ponto de referencia, 1/1/1600 foi um sabado.
        int dd = 1;
        int mm = 1;
        int yy = 1600;
        int day = 0;


        //descobriremos a proxima sexta-feira 13

        while (dd <= d || mm <= m || yy <= y || day != 6 || dd != 13){
            day++;
            day %= 7;

            boolean leapYear;
            if (yy % 400 == 0) leapYear = true;
            else if (yy % 100 == 0) leapYear = false;
            else leapYear = yy % 4 == 0;

            if (dd + 1 <= DAYS[mm] || (dd == 28 && leapYear))
                dd++;
            else{
                if (mm < 12) {
                    dd = 1;
                    mm++;
                }
                else {
                    dd = 1;
                    mm = 1;
                    yy++;
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Next Friday 13th is " + dd + "/" + mm + "/"+ yy);

    }
}
```

Here are the following input-output i got:
input:1 1 2000
output:Next Friday 13th is 13/4/2001

input:6 2 2011
output:Next Friday 13th is 13/4/2012

input:13 2 2003
output:(I had to close the program because it didnt end)

input:22 4 1998
output:(same thing as above)

Comment: "Any suggestions?" Yeah! Share the unit tests of the function too, not only the function.

Comment: Are you aware of the bitwise operator `|` in your loop condition?

Comment: @Mär what do you mean?

Comment: `||` <-- this is "or", `|` <-- this is "bitwise or". They are not the same thing.

Comment: hmm, ok. I just changed everything to "||" but it still does not work

Comment: Yes, however now it doesn't work for a different reason.

Comment: well, thanks anyway...

Comment: That's a very simple (and very inefficient) algorithm. Think about how you'd do the same process as a human, armed with a stack of calendars: You wouldn't look at each day of each month, you'd just look and see if the 13th was a friday, and if not, move onto the next month. Also, because you're not interested in years before the specified date, you just need to know which day of the week the year begins on...

Comment: @mar `|` is not only a bitwise OR operator, but also a non-short-circuiting boolean OR; contrary to `||` which is a short-circuiting boolean OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to adjust the condition for the while-loop.
You want to continue adding a day under following circumstances:

- Date mm/dd/yy is before m/d/y (not yet after the given date)
- Date mm/dd/yy is no friday (`day != 6`)
- Date mm/dd/yy is no 13th (`dd != 13`)

The last two conditions are implemented the right way, but your check, if the date is in the "future", does not work correctly.
You might try this:

```
yy < y || (yy == y && mm < m) || (yy == y && mm == m && dd <= d)
```

Thus the total condition you need is

```
yy < y || (yy == y && mm < m) || (yy == y && mm == m && dd <= d) || day != 6 || dd != 13
```

**EDIT** to explain why you run into an endless loop with d >= 13:

Your condition has `dd <= d` and `dd != 13`. Thus `dd` needs to be equal to 13 and bigger than (at least) 13 (the provided `d`) for the condition to evaluate to false. This obviously will never be the case, thus you get an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

The actual cause is that your condition of

```
while (dd <= d || mm <= m || yy <= y || day != 6 || dd != 13){
```

will be true if any of the operands is true, which is incorrect. Imagine the case when `d > 13`. In this case `dd` will be smaller than `d` when `dd` is 13. But the `while` loop's condition can only be `false` if `dd` is 13. Hence, if `d > 13`, then the cycle will be infinite. Another issue is that if, for instance `m` is representing december, than none none of the Friday 13th of any earlier months will be identified.

The correct algorithm is as follows:

```
d <- currentDate
found <- false
if day(d) <= 13 then
    currentDate <- findTheDateAt13th(currentDate)
    found <- isFriday(currentDate)
end if
while (not found) do
    currentDate <- findNextDateAt13th(currentDate)
    found <- isFriday(currentDate)
end while
```